# incomplete types:<anonymous ActionListener>cannot be converted to component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compiler-errors

I am trying to show a message dialog using Swing showing if the password that I entered is not equal the password stored inside the array but it gives me an error:

```
incomplete types:<anonymous ActionListener> cannot be converted to component
```

When I use `this` statement:

```
jRadioButton3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Manager[] arr = new Manager[3];
        arr[c].setEmpID(Integer.valueOf(jTextField1.getText()));
        arr[c].setEmpName(jTextField2.getText());
        arr[c].setPassword(jTextField5.getText());
        if (!arr[c].getPassword().equals(jTextField4.getText())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Password", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "this" in your parameters refers to the ActionListener, which is not a Swing component.

You want something like:

```
JButton button = (JButton)ae.getSource();
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( button );
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Invalid Password", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```